# (using $pull with $each in mongoose) why we cannot use both? _ NodeJs mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

maybe my question is dum or I don't know how to use $ each.I have an array of ids I want to pull from a document that has an array field in it.

```
let my_list = ['1', '2', '6', '432']
foo.findOneAndUpdate({
        _id: "some_id",
    },
        {
            $pull: { access_to: { $each: my_list } }
        }
    ));
```

but I get this error :

> Can't use $each with Array.

but why we can not use these two $ operators together?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use $pullAll instead as:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pullAll/

```
foo.findOneAndUpdate({
        _id: "some_id",
    },
        {
            $pullAll: { access_to: my_list  }
        }
    ));
```

Comment: yeah I found it too . but question remains what is the logical reason behind , you cant use these together?

Comment: its given in docs that it can only be used with push and addtoset
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/each/